# Trying to bold the text while calling the inline in my BI Publisher - RTF template

Tags: inline-styles

In a BI Publisher RTF template, I would like to make the text bold when I call@inlines.

call@inlines:persdata_land

I don't want to manipulate the subtemplate incase we need it for another template.

Answer (score 0):

I typically would use the Conditional Format functionality that is available in the plugin.